# Correcting colours of booking widget (HTML/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a booking widget where I want to make all fields white - I figured out the button, button text and some other elements, but the inside of the clickable fields still shows as grey. Given the dark background, every piece of the widget should be white.

Widget in its current state:

[image: screenshot]

Second issue, is on mobile, when selecting the dates of the booking, it seems to overlap other elements on the site, as seen here. Selecting dates makes the calendar cover the "Our Properties" text, with the text being visible still:
[image: screenshot]

For reference, the website is [kaliberrentals.com](https://www.kaliberrentals.com/).

As for the code of the widget, I have:

```
    <div class="uplisting-widget"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d2n64sniz4ei2k.cloudfront.net/property-search- f6490f4d.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.uplistingSearchWidget.init({
        baseUrl: 'https://kaliber.bookeddirectly.com/g/',
        showLocation: false,
        locationText: 'All cities',
        locations: ['REPLACE WITH CITY', 'REPLACE WITH CITY'],
        color: '#fff',
        insertAt: '.uplisting-widget',
        guestsMin: 1,
        guestsMax: 99,
        textColor: '#000',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        buttonText: 'Submit',
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.